# INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TABLE;

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to do an INSERT / SELECT, this means INSERT in the TARGET_TABLE the records of the SOURCE_TABLE, with this assumption:

The SOURCE and the TARGET table have only a SUBSET of common columns, this means in example:

==> The SOURCE TABLE has ALPHA, BETA and GAMMA columns;
==> The TARGET TABLE has BETA, GAMMA and DELTA columns.

What is the most efficient way to produce INSERT / SELECT statements, respecting the assumption that not all the target columns are present in the source table?

The idea is that the PL/SQL script CHECKS the columns in the source table and in the target table, makes the INTERSECTION, and then produces a dynamic SQL with the correct list of columns.

Please assume that the columns present in the target table, but not present in the source table, have to be left NULL.

**I wish to extract the data from SOURCE into a set of INSERT statements for later insertion into the TARGET table.**

**You can assume that the TARGET table has more columns than the SOURCE table, and that all the columns in the SOURCE table are present in the TARGET table in the same order.**

Thank you in advance for your useful suggestions!

Comment: Reading through the comments it looks like you want to extract the data from SOURCE into a set of `INSERT` statements for later insertion into the TARGET table. If so, then perhaps you should update the description to express that better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle, You can get common columns with this SQL query:

```
select column_name
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'TABLE_1'
intersect
select column_name
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'TABLE_2'
```

Then you iterate a cursor with the mentioned query to generate a comma separated list of all values returned. Put that comma separated string into a `varchar2` variable named `common_fields`. Then, you can:

```
sql_sentence := 'insert into TABLE_1 (' || 
                 common_fields || 
                 ') select ' || 
                 common_fields ||
                 ' from TABLE_2';
execute immediate sql_sentence;
```

Comment: How can I modify this solution if SQL_SENTENCE has to contain the EXACT VALUES of the common_fields?

Comment: Please assume that COMMON_FIELDS can be DATE, NUMBER or VARCHAR2 datatype.

Comment: SQL_SENTENCE := 'INSERT INTO TABLE_1 VALUES ('CUSTOM STRING', TO_DATE ('01/01/1980','DD/MM/YYYY'), -10, 123)';

Comment: I would like to have in the SQL_SENTENCE the explicit values of the common fields, not their names.

Comment: I see... You won't be able to do that in ONE sentence. You need multiple inserts to do that I guess...

Comment: Of course, multiple inserts for multiple records. These multiple inserts have to be executed with delay, so I store them in a table, for example. This is the reason why I need the REAL values, and not the columns' names.

Comment: I see... Yes, you can use a similar approach. You will have to use a cursor to get the values, and then insert them one by one with another dynamic SQL sentence. Keep in mind though that this will be way slower (performance wise).

Comment: Could you help me for doing this?

Comment: If you are on 11g you could use listagg (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm) to assemble the column names so you don't have to loop through them.